# Is there a better way to split a container of a non-movable type based on a predicate

Tags: c++

I want to ask for an alternative solution to this problem. I am dealing with this C/C++ style interface that has this non-moveable type `NonMovableType` defined roughly as follows:

```
union union_type {
  int index;
  const char* name;
};

struct NonMovableType 
{
   std::initializer_list<union_type> data;
};
```

This is something I cannot change, despite the unfortunate use of unions and initializer lists.
We then have some container of this type, say

```
std::vector<NonMovableType> container
```

and we want to split `container` based on some predicate for each of its members. Now, if it was a movable type i'd do

```
std::vector<NonMovableType> container;
std::vector<NonMovableType> result;

auto iter = std::partition(container.begin(), container.end(), [](const NonMovableType& element){
     return element.data.size(); // the predicate
});
std::move(iter, container.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
container.erase(iter, container.end());
```

I could then trust `container` and `result` would contain the elements split by the predicate, that way I could then iterate over each one individually and do the necessary processing on them.

This wont work however because `std::move` and `std::partition` both require a movable type. Instead I have to result to the rather slow:

```
std::vector<NonMovableType> container;
std::vector<NonMovableType> result_a;
std::vector<NonMovableType> result_b;

std::copy_if(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(result_a), [](const NonMovableType& element){
      return element.data.size();
});
std::copy_if(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(result_b), [](const NonMovableType& element){
      return !element.data.size();
});
container.clear();
```

And so, my question is, is there any better way to do this? I suppose calling it a 'non movable type' may be wrong, its only the union and the initializer list which are giving me problems, so really the question becomes is there a way to move this type safely, and do so without having to change the initial class. Could it also be possible to wrap `NonMovableType` into another class and then use pointers as opposed to a direct type?

Comment: Simple and lazy solution: use list instead of the vector.

Comment: @trokymchuk what benefit would that bring, im not used to using list. Thanks

Comment: list elements could be easily moved to another list. Take a look at `std::list::splice`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice. It does not copy or move elements, just rearrange the pointers.

Comment: *"This wont work however because std::move and std::partition both require a movable type."* It should work... you would *"just"* have copies instead of moves...

Comment: I deleted my answer, as you were right. I didn't realize the problem was actually in std::partition.

I would simply go for the two copy_if solution. Yes, it's two iterations. And yes, it copies data. But it's straight-forward, easy to read, and as @alagner has mentioned: you don't have to optimize up front. It's a O(2n) solution which is equivalent to O(n) in terms of growth rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really a performance problem or are you trying to optimize in advance?

As for a general answer: it really depends. I would probably try to achieve everything in a single pass (especially if the original container has a lot of elements), e.g.

```cpp
for (const auto& el : container) {
  if (el.data.size()) out1.push_back(el);
  else out2.push_back(el);
}
```

which can be easily generalized into:

```cpp
template<typename ForwardIt, typename OutputIt1, typename OutputIt2, typename Pred>
void split_copy(ForwardIt b, ForwardIt e, OutputIt1 out1, OutputIt2 out2, Pred f)
{
    for(; b != e; ++b) {
        if (f(*b)) {
            *out1 = *b;
            ++out1;
        } else {
            *out2 = *b;
            ++out2;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this going to be faster than partitioning first and copying later?
I can't tell, maybe. Both solutions are imho ok in terms of readability, as for their performance - please measure and get back with the numbers. :)

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/axMsKGq7d

EDIT: operating on heap-allocated objects and vectors of pointers to them, as well as operating on lists is sth. to be verified in practice, for your particular use case. It might help, of course, but again, measure first, optimize later.